# Prove If $a \equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{n}$, then $a + c \equiv b + d \pmod{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Using the definition of congruence $\pmod{n}$, prove that if $a \equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $c \equiv d \pmod{n}$, then $a + c \equiv b + d \pmod{n}$.

I've seen a couple of different examples of how to do this, mostly using $s$ and $t$, but I am really struggling to understand the proof, and how to write it.

Answer (score 6):

Write $a\equiv b\pmod n$ as: "there exists $s\in\Bbb Z$ such that $b=a+sn$". Similarly for $c\equiv d\pmod n$ (here use another variable, say $t\in\Bbb Z$). Now write out $b+d$ and simplify, isolating a term $a+c$. Conclude.

Answer (score 1):

concrete methods:

- $a\equiv b \pmod   n \implies n|(a-b)$ $ c \equiv d \pmod   n \implies n|(c-d)$
- $$n|(a-b)+(c-d)$$
- $$a+c\equiv b+d \pmod  n$$